# Retrieving data in packets from JSON file

Tags: c#, json, wpf, parsing

I have a JSON file that grow bigger and bigger every week or so that is used to load the data in it to my MainViewModel and its associated MainView but this takes longer and longer (duh!) and the startup time is very poor because of it. How can I retrieve the data from my serialised JSON file 1 item at a time so that the data gets retrieved in packets and not having to wait for the whole data to be retrieved before showing the data?

Comment: I think you may need to redesign the input. Can't you use a database. You could transform the data into tables and rewrite your code to read what you need from the tables

Comment: You need a streaming parser like XmlReader. As far as I know, none exist for JSON.

Comment: Actually, Newtonsoft Json can use stream as input

Comment: For a short term solution that may work but as data is growing this is going to be more of a pain on the long run.

Comment: Yea, this sounds like a solution problem, to me, rather than just how to read more data with a stream. As the data expands loading time will expand (even to a point where a stream doesn't help...) Is it possible to break the single JSON file down into separate files so that you only load the data you need for the current view? Otherwise, if you expect JSON to continue to grow, then you should include a loading screen in the design so your users know that actual data is loading during start-up.

Comment: Ok well thanks. gives me a lot to think about